# Retrieve event args from getPastLogs

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, rpc

When we use `web3.eth.getPastLogs` it returns topic and data properties together with rest data. Does it possible to retrieve event args parsing just data and topic as filter? Without to make additional request to node like `myContract.getPastEvents`?

The reason to use such approach is to avoid additional requests to remote Ethereum node. So the goal to fetch events from multiple contracts by one request.

For example

```
web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    fromBlock: 'latest',
    toBlock: 'latest',
    address: [
        "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe",
        "0xEA13ff054fF3fAb986442A29121A32803f1dAf7D",
        ... // multiple contract addresses here
    ],
    topics:[ 
         web3.utils.sha3('Transfer(address,address,uint256)') // or uint ?
    ]
})
```

So how to parse returned result where data property converts to human readable event args format?

Answer (score 2):

> `data`: `String` - contains one or more 32 Bytes non-indexed arguments of the log.
>
> `topics`: `Array of Strings` - Array of 0 to 4 32 Bytes `DATA` of indexed log arguments. (In solidity: The first topic is the hash of the signature of the event (e.g. `Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256))`, except if you declared the event with the anonymous specifier.)

Let's consider event `Transfer` with definition:

`event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`

signature `Transfer(address,address,uint256)`

signature hash `sha3('Transfer(address,address,uint256)')` = `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

Scenario:

Mint 10 tokens to account `0xf1DFA31Bd1B4aC386868ced5f2b7e224A347aC8f`, mint emits `Transfer` event from `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` to `0xf1DFA31Bd1B4aC386868ced5f2b7e224A347aC8f`

```
{
    "address": "0x6853168f0985fc08e6dc49f4e3a37f52ae98951b",
    "blockHash": "0xfce1ce22fecfe019fb28ccdc5bfc3477ebc5e6f7d84bbd6687b25d386a0600a6",
    "blockNumber": 4291221,
    "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a",  // 3rd non-indexed parameter
    "logIndex": 6,
    "removed": false,
    "topics": [
        "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",  // signature
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",  // 1st indexed parameter
        "0x000000000000000000000000f1dfa31bd1b4ac386868ced5f2b7e224a347ac8f"   // 2nd indexed parameter
    ],
    "transactionHash": "0x7cee18327143b52832ea13deba7c4397ed8d63b60811567cdf7b217a40b1b410",
    "transactionIndex": 9
}
```

All parameters in hex format

```
parseInt('0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a', 16) = 10
```